# Wand with webp support on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, imagemagick, puppet, wand

I am trying to use Wand (http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3.5/) library to transform images server side.

I installed libmagickwand-dev on my Ubuntu server.

I can work with jpg and png images but I get an error message when trying to transform a webp image:

```
no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/346
```

Any idea how to get Want support webp images on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

UPDATE: I have also installed libwebp-dev, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/251950/imagemagick-convert-cant-convert-to-webp/251954#251954

Unfortunately due to a bug in Ubuntu I had to recompile imagemagick myself.